# Benefits of using a drum backing track when practicing?

Tags: practice, rhythm, improvisation

I've been practicing my oud and using the following [backing track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAzNXMUD-Jk). I'm wondering if anyone has been using a rhythmic/drum backing track and what benefits have you seen versus not using one? (Doesn't matter what instrument.)

edit: not even remotely the same as the question identified as "duplicate".

Comment: The duplicate answers this question very well, despite the question being worded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People tell me I keep good time when playing.  If this compliment is true, I put a lot of it down to years of keyboard/drum machine/vocals gigs round the clubs in my (relative) youth.  And later, playing with some excellent drummers. You soon learn the difference between 'expressive rubato' and simple not keeping up or rushing!

Yes, if you're playing rhythmic music, some rhythm accompaniment is an excellent idea.

Comment: Absolutely! I did years with very unforgiving drum machines. For serious dancing, they're great. So many players don't seem to be able to play along with them, though.